# Autosave Status in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor

I have gotten stuck on a rather simple aspect of the autosave feature and that is the current status of the action like found on the overview page: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html#demo. But it doesn't look like they actually reference it anywhere (example below).

[image]

My html is just:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="notes" id="notes">{!! $shipmentShortage->notes !!}</textarea>
```

My create script is below, the autosave feature works just fine, but the status just isn't there:

```
<script>
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#notes' ), {
        toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'undo', 'redo' ],
        image: {
            toolbar: [ 'imageStyle:full', 'imageStyle:side', '|', 'imageTextAlternative' ],
        },
        autosave: {
            save( editor ) {
              console.log(editor.getData());
                // The saveData() function must return a promise
                // which should be resolved when the data is successfully saved.
                return saveData( editor.getData() );
            }
        }
    } );
    // Save the data to a fake HTTP server (emulated here with a setTimeout()).
function saveData( data ) {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        setTimeout( () => {
            console.log( 'Saved', data );
            $.ajax({
              url: '/osd/shortages/update',
              type: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              },
              data: {
                'shortage_id':'{{$shipmentShortage->id}}',
                'notes': data,
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (response) {
                console.log('saved');
              }
            });

            resolve();
        }, 5000 );
    } );
}
// Update the "Status: Saving..." info.
function displayStatus( editor ) {
    const pendingActions = editor.plugins.get( 'PendingActions' );
    const statusIndicator = document.querySelector( '#editor-status' );

    pendingActions.on( 'change:hasAny', ( evt, propertyName, newValue ) => {
        if ( newValue ) {
            statusIndicator.classList.add( 'busy' );
        } else {
            statusIndicator.classList.remove( 'busy' );
        }
    } );
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely correct. They show us a sexy status updater but don't give us the code for it. Here is what I extracted from the demo page by looking at the page source. This should give you the Status updates as you asked. Let me know if you have any questions.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="snippet-autosave">
    <textarea name="content" id="CKeditor_Notes">            
        Sample text
    </textarea>
</div>
<!-- This will show the save status -->
<div id="snippet-autosave-header">
    <div id="snippet-autosave-status" class="">
         <div id="snippet-autosave-status_label">Status:</div>
              <div id="snippet-autosave-status_spinner">
                   <span id="snippet-autosave-status_spinner-label"></span>
                   <span id="snippet-autosave-status_spinner-loader"></span>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    #snippet-autosave-header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--ck-color-toolbar-background);
    border: 1px solid var(--ck-color-toolbar-border);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: var(--ck-border-radius);
    /*margin-top: -1.5em;*/
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    border-top: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

#snippet-autosave-status_spinner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

#snippet-autosave-status_spinner-label {
    position: relative;
}

    #snippet-autosave-status_spinner-label::after {
        content: 'Saved!';
        color: green;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: var(--ck-spacing-medium);
    }

/* During "Saving" display spinner and change content of label. */
#snippet-autosave-status.busy #snippet-autosave-status_spinner-label::after {
    content: 'Saving...';
    color: red;
}

#snippet-autosave-status.busy #snippet-autosave-status_spinner-loader {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    animation: autosave-status-spinner 1s linear infinite;
}

#snippet-autosave-status,
#snippet-autosave-server {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#snippet-autosave-server_label,
#snippet-autosave-status_label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: var(--ck-spacing-medium);
}

#snippet-autosave + .ck.ck-editor .ck-editor__editable {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

#snippet-autosave-lag {
    padding: 4px;
}

#snippet-autosave-console {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: normal;
    background: #2b2c26;
    transition: background-color 500ms;
}

    #snippet-autosave-console.updated {
        background: green;
    }

@keyframes autosave-status-spinner {
    to {
        transform: rotate( 360deg );
    }
}
</style>
```

The rest is just initializing the Editor just like on the demo page [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html#demo).

```
              ClassicEditor
                    .create(document.querySelector('#CKeditor_Notes'), {
                        autosave: {
                            save(editor) {
                                return saveData(editor.getData());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                        .then(editor => {
                            window.editor = editor;

                            displayStatus(editor);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.error(err.stack);
                        });

            // Save the data to Server Side DB.
            function saveData(data) {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log('Saved', data);

                        SaveDataToDB(data)

                        resolve();
                    });
                });
            }

            // Update the "Status: Saving..." info.
            function displayStatus(editor) {
                const pendingActions = editor.plugins.get('PendingActions');
                const statusIndicator = document.querySelector('#snippet-autosave-status');

                pendingActions.on('change:hasAny', (evt, propertyName, newValue) => {
                    if (newValue) {
                        statusIndicator.classList.add('busy');
                    } else {
                        statusIndicator.classList.remove('busy');
                    }
                });
            }
```